# Intel GMA 4500HD & vsync

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm struggling with a tearing problem in my OpenGL application.

I cant seem to find a driver for the GMA 4500HD (in my case running on a Thinkpad x200s) that supports the opengl extension WGL_EXT_swap_control.

Currently I have the 8.15.10.2182 driver installed, which I think is the latest.

I have set the "Vertical sync" parameter in the driver control Window, but it seem to do nothing.

Do I have to live with the tearing problem, or is there anything I can do so that the buffer swap occurs on vsync without the WGL_EXT_swap_control extension ?

Edit: I noticed that a demo application using Direct3d (11) do not suffer from tearing on the same type of hardware.

Comment: You should tells us a bit more about your current rendering code. Are you using glFlush/glFinish before your swapBuffers() call? If so, have you tried leaving those calls out? If not, have you tried putting them in (j/k, don't)?

Comment: So far its very simple, just adding the primitives and then do swapbuffers() , I guess the tearing is extra visible since I render tiles that scrolls over the screen vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a setting to enable VSync in the driver control panel?
Often you have to enable features there before opengl can see them.

Comment: Yea, its a setting called "vertical sync" thats have two options "on" and "application" , to be honest, I do not really know if this applies to Opengl or Direct3d or both...

Answer (score 0):

Support of `WGL_EXT_swap_control` is there since the [dawn of time](https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=39).

If you have any problem it can only be either due to you doing something wrong, or a driver bug (but this would seem kind of strange then, considering people on the net were [complaining](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490DHRSA2/how-disable-vertical-sync-using-commandline-or-registry) about the actual opposite if any). Check if the [control](https://web.archive.org/web/20090712041411/http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-030506.htm) [panel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005552.html) isn't forcing anything in this regard, and if you are calling the [actually right](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyglet-users/7yQ9viOu75Y) function?